# Selenium multiple browser testing. Only last browser receives cookies. TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, testng

I have been working on automated tests and are trying to skip the login page, by logging in one time, saving the cookies on a text file and then finally reading and adding the files on a new browser instance.

It works fine when I just create one browser at a time, but if I create multiple browser parallel, only one page receives the cookies (thus skipping the login page as intended).

Here is  the code:

My Setup(). This works perfect. I just login, saves the cookie data in text file and close the browser.

```
@BeforeClass
public void cookie_setup(){
    //Firefox
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumGecko/geckodriver.exe");
    webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
File file = new File("Cookies.data");
    try
    {
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter  Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);

        for ( Cookie ck: webdriver.manage().getCookies())
        {
            Bwrite.write((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()+";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));

            Bwrite.newLine();
        }
        Bwrite.close();
        fileWrite.close();
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    cookies = webdriver.manage().getCookies();
    webdriver.quit();
}
```

- Then I create a new firefox browser
- Reads the cookie data in the text file
- Add the the cookies to the page with:`webdriver.manage().addCookie(ck);

  ```
  @Test(threadPoolSize = 4,  invocationCount = 4)
  public void search() throws InterruptedException {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
                          "C:\\SeleniumGecko/geckodriver.exe");
  webdriver.navigate().to("http://pagethatrequirelogin/");

  try {
      File file = new File("Cookies.data");
      FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      String strline;
      while ((strline = Buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
          StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline, ";");
          while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String name = token.nextToken();
              String value = token.nextToken();
              String domain = token.nextToken();
              String path = token.nextToken();
              Date expiry = null;

              String val;
              if (!(val = token.nextToken()).equals("null")) {
                  expiry = new Date(val);
              }
              Boolean isSecure = Boolean.valueOf(token.nextToken());
              Cookie ck = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure);
              System.out.println(ck);
              webdriver.manage().addCookie(ck);

          }
      }
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
  }
  ```

  }

I use TestNG and with the parameters:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 4,  invocationCount = 4)
```

I create 4 firefox browers at the same time, but only one of browser receives the cookies and skip login page.

It works perfectly fine if I just create one browser at a time multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are perhaps having your `@Test` methods overwrite the webdriver instance. Here's a sample that shows how a thread-safe version of it would look like:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CookiesSample {
    private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private List<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() throws IOException {
        String text = "Cookies.data";
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(text));
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String name = token.nextToken();
                String value = token.nextToken();
                String domain = token.nextToken();
                String path = token.nextToken();
                Date expiry = null;

                String val = token.nextToken();
                if (!val.equals("null")) {
                    expiry = asDate(val);
                }
                Boolean isSecure = Boolean.valueOf(token.nextToken());
                Cookie ck = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure);
                cookies.add(ck);
            }
        });
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        cookies.forEach(driver.manage()::addCookie);
        drivers.set(driver);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        drivers.get().quit();
        drivers.remove();
    }

    @Test(threadPoolSize = 4, invocationCount = 4)
    public void testMethod() {
        drivers.get().get("http://pagethatrequirelogin/");
    }

    private static Date asDate(String text) {
        try {
            return DateFormat.getInstance().parse(text);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return new Date();
        }
    }
}
```